# compile error when use ordered type

Tags: scala

The rowset has a column of item_key whose type in Int. and I want to know whether that column is bigger than a specific value or not.

```
def bigger[T: Ordered](a: ResultSet, columnName: String, compare: T): Boolean =
    (a.getObject(columnName).asInstanceOf[Ordered[T]] > compare)


bigger[Int](rs, "item_key", 5034533);
```

But it throws the following compile error when calling bigger[Int](rs, "item_key", 5034533); where is the problem is?

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type Ordered[Int]
    - not enough arguments for method bigger: (implicit evidence$9: Ordered[Int])Boolean. Unspecified value parameter 
     evidence$9.
    - could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type Ordered[Int]
    - not enough arguments for method bigger: (implicit evidence$1: Ordered[Int])Boolean. Unspecified value parameter 
     evidence$1.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Ordered[T]` trait represents [a single, natural ordering for a type](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.math.Ordered) should be used as a mixin into a class, where you have to provide implementation for `compare(other : T)`. You're trying to use it as a *typeclass*. If you want an implicit ordering, which also means there can be multiple available orderings, you should use [`Ordering[T]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.math.Ordering) instead.

```
def bigger[T](a: ResultSet, columnName: String, compare: T)(implicit ord : Ordering[T]) =
    ord.gt(a.getObject(columnName).asInstanceOf[T], compare)
```

Now, if you want to use `Ordered`, that means all your types will have to mix in `Ordered[T]`:

```
def bigger[T <: Ordered[T]](a: ResultSet, columnName: String, compare: T) =
    a.getObject(columnName).asInstanceOf[T] > compare
```

which is probably **not** what you want. You won't be able to use it with, for example, `Int`, since it does not extend `Ordered[Int]`.

Other option would be to provide view bound:

```
def bigger[T <% Ordered[T]](a: ResultSet, columnName: String, compare: T) =
    a.getObject(columnName).asInstanceOf[T] > compare
```

which works fine (because there's a conversion from `Int` to `Ordered[Int]`), although I think that generally typeclass approach is now favored instead of view bounds - it's a bit subjective and if I'm wrong, please someone correct me.